# ionic2 blank screen after adding new Component

Tags: angular, ionic2

GitHub: https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/

I'm trying to add A new component call `Medicine` (located in **Pages** dir).
I have imported it to `app.modules.ts` and to `app.component.ts`,
after I imported it. I get a Blank Screen with this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load HomePage.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load HomePage.html undefined
```

I hope you guys help me, THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.component.ts, you need to add that page to array component.

```
this.pages = [
  { title: 'עמוד הבית', component: HomePage },
  { title: 'WhatEverTitle', component: Medicine },
 ];
```

Also import that page. Looks like your Medicine.html also need some refactoring.

I would suggest you to generate page using following command

```
 ionic g page Medicine
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to fix your app.component, but like Savan said, you need to look at Medicine.html. It should not have all of the usual doctype, heading, body, (etc..) tags. For testing purposes I deleted the content from Medicine.html, and added this

```
<ion-content>       
    <p color="dark">Title</p>
</ion-content>
```

Use the ionic cli to generate pages, components, and directives.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/